# Programmatically open a Remote url in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsip

Is there any way to open a remote url (i.e. a http url) within visual studio.

The [IVsUIShellOpenDocument.OpenStandardEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishellopendocument.openstandardeditor%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method sounds promising, but it needs an existing document.

Has anyone managed to get this working?

Comment: Do you mean you want the URL to be opened within a browser tab within the VS window?

Comment: Typically it will be an XML file that is being read from the url, I want it to open in the appropriate editor for its type, i.e. XML Code editor.